# How to call a server-side function right after closing a telerik RadWindow?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radwindow

I am trying to call a server-side method immediatly after closing a telerik RadWindow.
I have a pop-up RadWindow, and I want to perform a few operations in the client-side and server-side after that pop-up window is closed.
I've been looking for an event like OnClientClose, that the RadWindow has for calling 
a client-side method, but I couldn't find one.

Does anyone know how to create OnClose event or how should it be done properly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to have a client close event, and perform a postback by using `__doPostBack`, or if you have an AJAX panel control on the page, you can refresh it with its client-side `ajaxRequest` method.

On its own, it doesn't postback to the server on close by default.

HTH.

Comment: I used the ajaxRequest and it works fine for me. Thank you Brian!